# Counting a number of an object in all simulation repetition

Tags: r

I have R code for generating random samples and repeat the simulation large number of times , and it works well and gives me the data I wanted  to use to calculate new variable I call it ED, and the mathematical form to calculate it is N^2* (theta_new)%*%sigma_inverse %*% trans,  what I want is to obtain the value of ED in each simulation and print it. After that I would like to count the total number of ED>7.815 in all simulations and calculate the percentage of that number.

I tried the following R code but it does not work properly.

```
# Initialize the counter
  n_greater_total <- 0
  
  # Calculate the ED value for each simulation
  ED <- c()
  for (i in 1:n_simulations) {
    
    # Calculate the ED value for the full sample
    ED_current <- N^2* (theta_new)%*%sigma_inverse %*% trans
    ED <- c(ED, ED_current)
    
    # Print the ED value
    print(paste("ED for simulation", i, "is", ED_current))
    
    # Check if the ED value is greater than 7.815
    if (ED_current >= 7.815) {
      
      # If yes, increment the counter
      n_greater_total <- n_greater_total + 1
    }
  }
  
  # Calculate the total number of ED values greater than 7.815
  total_greater <- sum(ED > 7.815)
  
  # Calculate the percentage of ED values greater than 7.815
  percentage <- (total_greater / n_simulations) * 100
  
  # Print the results
  print("Total number of values greater than 7.815:")
  print(total_greater)
  
  print("Percentage of ED values  greater than 7.815:")
  print(percentage)
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? Can you let us know the expected result?

Comment: Tried the code with random number generator. I can't find a mistake. What does not work properly?

Comment: For *"calculate the percentage of that number"*, do you mean `sum(ED > 7.815) / length(ED)`?